# Enviar array via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net

Necesito enviar un array utilizando una llamada ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost:24234/api/SendPushNotification",
    success: {
        Function(result) {
            Console.log(result);
        }
    },
    data: {
        'user_id': '1',
        'body_param': 'body',
        'title_param': 'title'      
    },
    headers: { 
        'Token': 'ccTtUKQS32PjzMYQEzH2OUQN8nJpsCUXg7iWRYA7cEpAJLoNEWCKr2NcQyFUbdV4' 
    }
});
```

¿Cómo se podría hacer?

PD: donde va user id, iran una cantidad "ilimitada de usuarios segun filtros internos.

Como lenguaje servidor VB. Es para un webservice que se encarga de enviar notificaciones. Actualmente ya funciona enviando identificadores de uno en uno. Pero es inviable teniendo en cuenta lo que tarda en realizar la llamda al ws etc...

Comment: Y que lenguajes utilizas del lado del servidor?

Comment: @Einer Uso VB. Es para un webservice que se encarga de enviar notificaciones. Actualmente ya funciona enviando identificadores de uno en uno. Pero es inviable teniendo en cuenta lo que tarda en realizar la llamda al ws etc...

Comment: puedes usar un json, o un diccionario, para enviarlos  var datos = {}

Comment: @EdwinCubillos podrias ponerme un ejemplo? Si yo tengo por ejemplo ['1','11','111','2','22','222',...]

Comment: Pues yo envio tanto diccionarios como listas o arrays,  por ajax y no tengo problema data: {
        'user_id': [ '1', '2']
        'body_param': 'body',
        'title_param': 'title'      
    }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Buen día para hacer una consulta ajax es necesario que utilices el tag 'data' en los ítems que vas a parametrizar al hacer la petición, quedaría algo como lo siguiente:

```
var arr = ["Saab", ["Volvo", "Volvo2","Volvo3"], "BMW"];

var valParam = JSON.stringify(arr);

$.ajax({
        url: 'TuURL',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { tuArrJson: valParam} ,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.status);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

del lado del server recoges el value con Request y posteriormente lees el valor que llega de la siguiente manera:

```
$param = json_decode($_REQUEST['tuArrJson']);

  foreach($param  as $val){
     echo "<br> - valor: ".$val;
  }
```

como es en VB seria iterar con dos bucles como te muestro a continuación:

```
Dim numbers = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}

For index0 = 0 To numbers.GetUpperBound(0)
    For index1 = 0 To numbers.GetUpperBound(1)
        Debug.Write(numbers(index0, index1).ToString & " ")
    Next
    Debug.WriteLine("")
Next
```

Espero te sea de utilidad. Saludos.

Comment: es es si todo es un array, pero, y si yo tengo que enviar 3 parametros, dos de ellos fijos y el otro array.

Comment: Puedes realizarlo de la siguiente manera, seria manejar el concepto de arreglos multidimencionales y quedaria de la siguiente manera: var arrayMuchasDimensiones = [1, ["hola","que","tal"],5]; en este ejemplo vez dos posiciones escalares y otra que es la que contiene una estructura... para este caso un arreglo. Saludos.

Comment: me vale para el envio, ahora el problema es el recibir. La cosa es que el que recibe es VB. Pero abrire otra pregunta para eso.

Comment: Para recibir declara variables locales como la siguiente: For i = 1 To Request.Form("tuArrJson").Count 
    Response.Write Request.Form("tuArrJson")(i) & "<BR>" 
  Next ; posteriormente iteras y segun sea al identificar si es array o es escalar vas asignando o armando la estructura que requieres de la data

Comment: Echale un ojo a mi nueva pregunta porfa [Webservice recoge un json multidimensional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119679/webservice-recoge-un-json-multidimensional)