# Webservice recoge un json multidimensional

Tags: ajax, vb.net, webservice

Estoy realizando la siguiente llamada ajax a mi webservice.

```
var datos = {"user_id":"2","body_param":"body","title_param":"title","arr":{"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4}};
console.log(datos);
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost:24234/api/SendPushNotification",
    success: {
        function(result) {
            Console.log(result);
        }
    },
    data: datos,
    headers: { 
       'Token': 'ccTtUKQS32PjzMYQEzH2OUQN8nJpsCUXg7iWRYA7cEpAJLoNEWCKr2NcQyFUbdV4' 
    }
});
```

Por lo que se puede apreciar se envian datos multidimensionales. El problema tengo para recibir. He probado con arrays, listas,... y nada.

```
Public Sub SendPushNotification(user_id As Integer, body_param As String, title_param As String, arr() As String)
   Try
```

El unico que llega vacio es arr, el resto recibe sus valores adecuadamente.

Comment: ¿Por qué intentas enviar un json via GET?

Comment: Según veo puedes generar un obj y enviarlo en formato json para posteriormente leerlo con visual basic, te adjunto tres enlaces relacionados al tema, espero te sean de utilidad. Saludos. ** https://forums.asp.net/t/1764636.aspx?How+to+pass+array+to+WebMethod+using+jQuery+Ajax                    
 ** https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-and-Receive-JSON-objects-to-Web-Service-Methods-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx  
 ** https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-and-receive-JavaScript-Array-to-Web-Service-Web-Method-using-ASP.Net-AJAX.aspx