# Enviar Array JS Por ajax a PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

Capturo varios inputs (los value)de forma dinamica de la siguiente forma:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <input type="text" name="prueba" class="form-control-file nombrePaisIdioma"><br/><br/>
  <input type="text" name="prueba" class="form-control-file nombrePaisIdioma"><br/><br/>
  <input type="text" name="prueba" class="form-control-file nombrePaisIdioma"><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="prueba" class="form-control-file nombrePaisIdioma"><br/><br/>

  <input type="button" onclick="x();" class="btn btn-primary" id="enviardoc" value="Enviar Documentos">

<script type="text/javascript">

  function x(){

    var nombres_paises = {};

    $('.nombrePaisIdioma').each(function() {
        nombres_paises[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
        console.log(nombres_paises);

    });

        $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        data : {'nombres_paises': JSON.stringify(nombres_paises)},//capturo array  
        url : 'pruebacolor2.php',
        success : function(e){

          console.log(e);

        }
        });




}

</script>
```

Hasta acá vamos bien, ya que me los captura todos.

El problema es que en el PHP, Solo llega 1, el ultimo:

```
<?php


    $data = json_decode($_POST['nombres_paises']);
    var_dump($data);

?>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, ya que no se cual es el problema.

Gracias

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119648/enviar-array-via-ajax?rq=1 ¿Duplicado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema esta en esta linea:

```
nombres_paises[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
```

Estas adquiriendo el id de los inputs, pero los inputs no tienen id.  La solucion es agregar los ids a los inputs o simplemente puedes hacer:

```
nombres_paises.push($(this).val());
```

Comment: Gracias, justo lo que necesitaba